# public datagridview within user control is "locked" during design time when subclassing

Tags: c#, datagridview, user-controls, subclassing

I have a user control that has among other things a label AND a textbox control.  With this class, I set the textbox to have its modifier as "public", so when I subclass THIS control, I can get directly to the properties and such of the textbox in each instance where needed.  No problem.

Now, the problem.  I do the exact same thing but with a dataGridView control (and some others) within a user control.  Set ITs modifier to public with intent to derive this user control downstream.  Now, I try to derive this control to a NEW control and can't directly touch the dataGridView and add columns, sizing, etc directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried reproducing the described behavior and was able to do so with the GUI designer in VS 2008 using .Net 3.5.  I suspect you are running into [the same issue as this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774351/how-to-force-a-certain-usercontrol-design/1774720#1774720)

That means to get the desired behavior you may need to implement a custom designer.  There is even an example designer given by another person answering the question.  Please have a look and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation that I'm not going nuts.  My work-around was the rest of the common class elements are fine, only the DataGridView.  So, I've just hard-coded the adding of columns / types and the rest works fine.   So for now, I'll leave well-enough alone.  Thanks for the support link too.

Comment: @DRapp, NP. To be honest I was skeptical when I read your question, and appalled when I tried it and saw the described behavior... If I ever come up with a slick way of doing what you want i'll post the code.